# Inter partes review

Tags: us6771290, interpartes

USPTO Litigation Alert reports that "Google, Sony, Microsoft and Samsung requested inter partes review of" this patent.  See http://blog.whda.com/2013/10/google-microsoft-sony-facebook-samsung-gang-up-on-two-b-e-tech-patents-week-of-october-7-2013/#more-4599

What are the prior art documents being used to challenge this patent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case number of the Sony filing regarding US 6,771,29 is IPR2014-00029. It cites two things:

PCT App. Pub. WO 97/09682 (“Kikinis”)
6,049,831(“Gardell”)

Microsofts filing has Kikinis and excerpts from AOL for Dummies 3rd edition!